# Get most recent measurement

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that has has some measurements, ID and date.

The table is built like so

```
ID     DATE    M1    M2
1      2020     1    NULL
1      2020    NULL   15
1      2018     2    NULL
2      2019     1    NULL
2      2019    NULL   1
```

I would like to end up with a table that has one row per ID with the most recent measurement

```
ID M1 M2
1  1  15
2  1   1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *correlated* sub-query with aggregation :

```
select id, max(m1), max(m2)
from t 
where t.date = (select max(t1.date) from t t1 where t1.id = t.id)
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` combined with an aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, MAX(M1) AS M1, MAX(M2) AS M2
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY ID;
```

The row number lets us restrict to only records for each `ID` having the most recent year date.  Then, we aggregate to find the max values for `M1` and `M2`.

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you can use `lag(ignore nulls)`:

```
select id, coalesce(m1, prev_m1), coalesce(m2, prev_m2)
from (select t.*, 
             lag(m1 ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_m1,
            lag(m2 ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_m2,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```